# Recording Audio on Google CoLab

Tags: python, audio-recording

I can't find any recent info on this topic. I'm trying to install PyAudio, but keep getting this:

```
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/  
Collecting pyaudio  
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)  
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio  
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error  
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio  
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio  
Failed to build pyaudio  
Installing collected packages: pyaudio  
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error  
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tkkycth3/pyaudio_6fb8f7ed14f14ac284f31533f961f7b0/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tkkycth3/pyaudio_6fb8f7ed14f14ac284f31533f961f7b0/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0kpe7_c3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/pyaudio   
Check the logs for full command output.
```

I looked it up and apparently it's outdated for the version of Python that Google CoLab uses, so what should I use instead?? Tried sounddevice but apparently that uses PortAudio, which isn't on Google CoLab either ("OSError: PortAudio library not found" is what I got from that).

Comment: Keep in mind that CoLab code isn't running on your computer - so what exactly do you think `pyaudio` would be able to record, even if it worked?  The sound of all the cooling fans in Google's datacenter?

Comment: Oh bummer. I did not realize that. That makes sense though - thank you.